# Cannot compile javadoc with Ant

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I'm working on a Java project, and would like to not only compile the entire application but also the javadoc documentation using Apache Ant.

Currently, my compile target in my build.xml script looks like this:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
    <javadoc 
      sourcefiles="${src.dir}" 
      destdir="${doc.dir}/forecast"
      classpath="classpath"
      author="true"
      version="true"
      use="true"
      windowtitle="${App-name}"
      doctitle="&lt;h1&gt;${App-name}&lt;/h1&gt;" />
  </target>
```

My source files are to be found in the src/com//forecast directory, and all have the header

```
package com.<company_name>.forecast
```

However, when I run
ant compile
I get the following output:

```
[javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
  [javadoc] 1 error
  [javadoc] javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "/home/linus/fo/forecast/src/com/<company_name>/forecast"
```

and no javadoc is created. I think I've tried almost all combinations of possible Javadoc properties, but to no avail. What am I missing?!
Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Linus

Comment: Could you provide the package/folder structure of your project ?

Comment: It's specified in the question, but all my java files reside in the folder src/com/<company_name>/forecast and I'd like the docs to go into doc/forecast

Comment: Based on what's given to `<javac>`, `<javadoc>` should have a `classpathref` attribute, not `classpath`.

Comment: By the way, the literal string "<company_name>" doesn't actually exist anywhere, right? A package name with "<" and ">" characters would certainly be considered illegal.

Comment: No, this is substituted by the actual company name :)

Answer (score 1):

try using below command.

```
javadoc -sourcepath ./src *.java -d ./docs
```

Comment: Well, yes, this works fine. However, I'd like to do it in my ant script

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package names are not getting identified properly. Could you try specifying the packagenames parameter.

More information is available [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html)

Example:

```
<javadoc packagenames="com.dummy.test.*"
       sourcepath="src"
       excludepackagenames="com.dummy.test.doc-files.*"
       defaultexcludes="yes"
       destdir="docs/api"
       author="true"
       version="true"
       use="true"
       windowtitle="Test API">  </javadoc>
```